# Get pip package in Python2.7

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, pip, yum

I have installed python2.7 in my RHEL6.7 machine which is having python2.6 as default .

Then I installed `pip` package using command `sudo yum install python-pip`.

Now the pip package is available in python2.6 alone, not in python2.7. How can I get pip package installed in `python2.7`?

Comment: run this file with the python version you want it to have.. [here](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py) python2.7 get-pip.py

Answer (score 1):

I assume on your system default python=2.6, the version you want to install pip for python=2.7 so:

```
$ python
this is default python

$ python2
python2.7

$ python2 get-pip.py
```